# How can I prevent database being written to again when the browser does a reload/back?

Tags: database, perl, cgi, idempotent

I'm putting together a small web app that writes to a database (Perl CGI & MySQL).  The CGI script takes some info from a form and writes it to a database.  I notice, however, that if I hit 'Reload' or 'Back' on the web browser, it'll write the data to the database again. I don't want this.

What is the best way to protect against the data being re-written in this case?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do not use GET requests to make modifications! Be [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer); use POST (or PUT) instead the browser should warn the user not to reload the request. Redirecting ([using HTTP redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx)) to a receipt page using a normal GET request after a POST/PUT request will make it possible to refresh the page without getting warned about resubmitting.

*EDIT:*

I assume the user is logged in somehow, and therefore you allready have some way of tracking the user, e.g. session or similar.

You could make a timestamp (or a random hash etc..) when displaying the form storing it both as a hidden field (*just besides the anti Cross-Site Request token I'm sure you allready have there*), and in a session variable (wich is stored safely on your server), when you recieve a the POST/PUT request for this form, you check that the timestamp is the same as the one in session. If it is, you set the timestamp in the session to something variable and hard to guess (timestamp concatenated with some secret string for instance) then you can save the form data. If someone repeats the request now you won't find the same value in the session variable and deny the request.

The problem with doing this is that the form is invalid if the user clicks back to change something, and it might be a bit to harsh, unless it's money you're updating. So if you have problems with "stupid" users who refresh and click the back-button thus accidentally reposting something, just using POST would remind them not to do that, and redirecting will make it less likely. If you have a problem with malicious users, you should use a timestampt too allthough it will confuse users sometimes, allthough if users is deliberately posting the same message over and over you probably need to find a way to ban them. Using POST, having a timestam, and even doing a full comparison of the whole database to check for duplicate posts, won't help at all if the malicious users just write a script to load the form and submit random garbage, automatically. (But cross-site-request protection makes that a lot harder)

Comment: The OP is complaining about his users messing up the system. Saying "make their browser try and stop them" is hardly a cast-iron solution to the problem.

Comment: No but it makes benign users less likely to do so, I added some ideas for further reducing the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Using a POST request will cause the browser to try to prevent the user from submitting the same request again, but I'd recommend using session-based transaction tracking of some kind so that if the user ignores the warnings from the browser and resubmits his query your application will prevent duplication of changes to the database. You could include a hidden input in the submission form with value set to a crypto hash and record that hash if the request is submitted and processed without error.

Answer (score 4):

I find it handy to track the number of form submissions the user has performed in their session.  Then when rendering the form I create a hidden field that contains that number.  If the user then resubmits the form by pressing the back button  it'll submit the old # and the server can tell that the user has already submitted the form by examining what's in the session to what the form is saying.

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't already using some sort of session-management (which would let you note and track form submissions), a simple solution would be to include some sort of unique identifier in the form (as a hidden element) that is either part of the main DB transaction itself, or tracked in a separate DB table. Then, when you are submitted a form you check the unique ID to see if it has already been processed. And each time the form itself is rendered, you just have to make sure you have a unique ID.

Comment: You issue a ticket number, then only punch the ticket once.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't trust the browser, so any talk about using POST rather than GET is mostly nerd flim-flam. Yes, the client might get a warning along the lines of "Did you mean to resubmit this data again?", but they're quite possibly going to say "Yes, now leave me alone, stupid computer".

And rightly so: if you don't want duplicate submissions, then it's your problem to solve, not the user's.

You presumably have some idea what it means to be a duplicate submission. Maybe it's the same IP within a few seconds, maybe it's the same title of a blog post or a URL that has been submitted recently. Maybe it's a combination of values - e.g. IP address, email address and subject heading of a contact form submission. Either way, if you've manually spotted some duplicates in your data, you should be able to find a way of programmatically identifying a duplicate at the time of submission, and either flagging it for manual approval (if you're not certain), or just telling the submitter "Have you double-clicked?" (If the information isn't amazingly confidential, you could present the existing record you have for them and say "Is this what you meant to send us? If so, you've already done it - hooray")

Answer (score 1):

I'd not rely on POST warnings from the browser. Users just click OK to make messages go away.

Anytime you'll have a request that needs to be one time only e.g 'make a payment', send a unique token down, that gets submitted back with the request. Throw the token out after it comes back, and so you can now tell when something is a valid submission (anything with a token that isn't 'active'). Expire active tokens after X amount of time, e.g. when a user session ends.

(alternately track the tokens that have come back, and if you have received it before then it is invalid.)

Comment: There's still an issue with race conditions, though. As soon as you receive the token, you need to check that it's not been used beforehand,  e.g. issue a SQL update command, and check whether the return value is 1 (you changed something) or 0E0 (you tried to change it to what it was already).

Answer (score 0):

Do a POST every time you alter data, but never return an HTML response from a post... instead return a redirect to a GET that retrieves the updated data as a confirmation page.  That way, there is no worry about them refreshing the page.  If they refresh, all that will happen is another retrieve, never a data-altering action.